# ATLAS automation in QGIS showing data from multiple layers (based on attribute from one of the layers)

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have a QGIS project with four layers: A, B, C and D.

I need to prepare an ATLAS automation based on layer A. On maps I want to see data from layers B, C and D (from A not necessarily) but the data needs to match to the attribute from table A selected for automation (the **Coverage layer** = Layer A, **Filter with** = values from 'Feature ID' column, **Sort by** = values from 'Feature ID')

Example:
Layer A - ATLAS automation based on values in attribute table from column: 'Feature ID' = 100, 101, 102 and so on.

Data from layers B, C, D visible on maps: features from layer B (C, D) where values in each attribute table from column 'Layer A Reference No' = 100, 101, 102 and so on.

I don't want to see the other features from layers B, C and D (where values are different than the ones selected for ATLAS automation (for example 87, 88 or 94)) for layer A - only the ones which match.

In the end I would see on the first map the data from layers B, C and D where attributes in the column 'Layer A Reference No' = **100** as this is the first map selected by ATLAS (based on Coverage layer A).

On the second map (where ATLAS selects value **101** from layer A) I would see only the data from layers B, C and D where attributes in the column 'Layer A Reference No' = **101**.

Is this possible without Python?

At the moment the only thing I can do is to query layers B, C and D in order to see on the map the data where the value in the column 'Layer A Reference No' = **100** (for the first map), **101** (for the second map) etc. and then use layer A for setting location.

But I have to prepare 200 maps!

Comment: You could set the layers' styles to be rule based. Your filter expression would be something like "layerAReference" = attribute(@atlas_feature, 'Feature ID') ...... Or "layerAReference" = @atlas_featureid

Comment: Thanks, Jesse. No luck so far. But thank for pointing me into this direction. I think that would be an answer. I will investigate it further and let you know what happens. "layerAReference" = attribute($atlasfeature, 'Feature ID') doesn't bring any data but at least is not rejected as an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the solution.

***Atlas generation*** TAB

Layers B, C and D

They need to be rule based (style) and need to contain the following rules (in Style):

**"Feature ID" = attribute( $atlasfeature , 'Feature ID')** - for visible records

**"Feature ID" <> attribute( $atlasfeature , 'Feature ID')** - for all records we don't want to see ( I styled it as transparent)

.....................................................................................................................................................................

Settings for the layer A, which works with ATLAS:

**Configuration** section:

Coverage layer: A

Hidden coverage layer: - TICKED

Filter with - NOT TICKED - this is important as the automation won't work otherwise

**Output** section:

**Output filename expression**: attribute($currentfeature, 'Feature ID') - this is not mandatory but will produce single files with the name = to the values from Feature ID column

**Single file export when possible** - NOT TICKED - this can be ticked in order to create a booklet, but not in my case

**Sort by**: Feature ID

.....................................................................................................................................................................

***Item properties*** TAB

Below are my settings for the Map in the **Item properties** panel

[image]

.....................................................................................................................................................................

Thanks Jesse again. I hope this will help the others as well at some point.

Regards,
Maciek Drozda

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, don't forget to mark your question as answered with the greyed-out tick.